# Video Uploader not working for mp4 with php

Tags: php, video, upload

I have an uploader that works great with images but not so great with videos. I need it for videos. Ive already increased the file size in php.ini Anyone spot an error here? I just need it for mp4 videos.

The uploader responds with invalid file. Im uploading mp4 videos.

The code is really basic but im still missing something.

offline, im using xampp and online im using godaddy as my host.

PHP code:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you get $extension value for mp4 video ..?

Comment: Its echo-ing back mp4

Comment: Try to print what actually you are getting for mp4$_FILES["file"]["type"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, thanks for the help. I figured it out. After hours....and hours........AND HOURS googling, making changes, and figuritivly beating my head against the wall, I have found that godaddy only allows a maximum of 128mb to be uploaded client-side. Not to be confused with the maximum file size a godaddy user can upload to their hosting account which is much, much larger.

If anyone else has this issue with video uploads, there is a video converter that will DRASTICALLY reduce the amount of space a video takes up. It says it was made for people who use lightworks editor but Ive used it a bunch already with several videos. Too a 570mb video down to 90mb and a 5.1gb video down to 200mb.

http://eyeframeconverter.wordpress.com/

I also did the following steps

1) drag a video into the eye-fram program

2) hit the convert button on bottom

3) make sure the settings are the following after hitting convert

-Editting -->>  LW FREE Mpeg2 I-Frame HD - Proxy Quarter Size

-Delivery -->>  H264 MP4 Profile High

I really really hope this helps someone. Its frustrating when you cant pinpoint an answer with google and you have to call tech support.

------EDIT------

The following link backs up the GoDaddy restriction if you go to the section under how to change your limit size, it tells you there is a maximum that you can set it to.
Chances are, if this changes, the link will be updates.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1475/what-is-the-php-upload-limit-on-linux-hosting-accounts

Answer (score 3):

you have to modify the **POST** max size, not only the *file upload size*, in php.ini

It should look like this if you want to disable the limit:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=0
```

And of course the file limit:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=1000M
```

Hope this help you to skip converting the video.

Regards.

Comment: Go daddy doesnt allow the override past their set limit. You can increase the limit over their default, but they max out at a low number(when dealing with videos.)

Max does nothing in this situation. Good thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy will let you make a php5.ini file of your own and you can change the upload settings to 4 gigs if you want. then all you do once uploaded the new php5.ini to your godaddy account you just have to shut your host down and restart it in the godaddy control panel.

Comment: Have you tested this? I tried it the same day and changed it to 2gb and it still failed after it reached a certain maximum amount. I dont remember how much it was but was under a gig if I remember right. The customer service rep told me that although it will increase the size, it will not increase it past their limit which was waaaaay under a gig at the time of this posting. If you did test it, do you have an example of how you did it? It could have worked because of the way you set it. Might be a workaround worth using.

Comment: In the below link, if you go down the page, right after it states that you can change the amount, it also shows the maximum it can be changed to.
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1475/what-is-the-php-upload-limit-on-linux-hosting-accounts